# Top Percentile by Group

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

everyone. Can anyone please help me with the following? Any pointers or assistance is appreciated!

I have a subset of the dataset with +500,000 rows that looks like this

```
|— Group —|— Name —|— Value1 —|— Value2 —|
```

Within each group, **I'm trying to identify the names in the top 5 and top 10 percentile of Value 1**, so that I can proceed to compute the sum of value 2 for each of the identified percentiles.

So far I've been able to create a pivot table that looks like this.

```
           |----------|--Sum Val1--|--Sum Val2--|
|--GroupA--|----------|     Totals for GroupA
|----------|-Name A1--|     Values.......
|----------|-Name A2--|     Values.......
    ...
|----------|-Name An--|     Values.......
|--GroupB--|----------|     Totals for GroupB
    ...                     Values.......
|--GroupZ--|----------|     Totals for GroupZ
```

I could identify the percentiles manually, but I imagine there is an easier way. I've done several searches on how to proceed, but I only encounter procedures to find percentiles among the whole dataset.

Comment: You seem to be presenting a header row for some data, and a schematic for an intermediate work product that you believe might be useful but isn’t getting you what you want.  Try posting some actual data along with the headers and templates, and a representation of the results you want for that input data.  It doesn’t have to be *real, **live*** data — in fact, it’s better if it’s not. Groups can be “cat”, “dog”, “fox”, “red”, “blue”, “green”, etc.; names can be “Tom”, “Dick”, “Harry”, “John”, Paul”, George” and “Ringo”; values can be 1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 20, 40, 80.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I don't think there would be an easy way for that. You probably need to helper columns where you calculate sum by category (`SUMIF`) and percentile (`LARGE`, `SUMIFS`).

Answer (score 1):

The way your pivot table is setup, applying a top 10 filter to `Names` will find the top `Names` within each `Group`. If you want to find the top `Names` overall, you have to put the `Names` field before the `Group` field.

Here's a mockup I made:

[image: Original]

When I filter for Top 2 `Names`:

[image: Top 2 Names]

When I put `Names` as the top field and then filter for the Top 2:

[image: Corrected Top 2 Names]

---

As suggested in the comments, you could also add helper columns to your original data that calculate each rows impact and then determine if it's in the Top 10 and return TRUE/FALSE. You could then apply a filter to the pivot table to only show those with TRUE in that field.